# Current Best Practice for Modular Javascript Applications

Tags: javascript, mobile

Not looking to start a flamewar :)

I am looking to build a modular javascript app for mobile devices (green field implementation). So the requirements are that it needs to be relatively light weight, support deferred loading of sub modules based on runtime decision (like user preferences) and have minimal template & MVC capabilities. The communication with backend is probably going to be based on websocket API (if it changes anything). Think something like www.twitter.com that needs to run inside Mobile Safari.

I am competent with jQuery and I heard about a lot of newer javascript frameworks (backbone.js, require.js, zepto.js and so on) but haven't had a chance to use them. I doubt I have enough time to learn and prototype with them all so I am looking for some community wisdom as to what is considered the best practice nowadays.

Thanks.

Comment: Opinion-based question.

Answer (score 2):

Good application structure is your friend when coding JavaScript apps. I took a look at Spine and Backbone, but ended up using [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com). The major reasons:

- Based on jQuery (so every jQuery plugin you find on the web will just integrate nicely)
- Provides a default way of organizing your app (according to a plugin/mvc architecture
- Promotes best practices (testing etc...)
- EJS as templating engine
- Easily extensible
- Extremely well [documented](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!)
- Build-in productivity tools to generate code, compress code, JS dependency management

Maybe you could combine it with jQuery mobile to suite your needs.

It might suite your need since:

- *Modularity*: create plugins/MVC modules for each module of your app
- *Deferred loading*: Steal (build-in dependency management system) loads your stuff based on when they're accessed
- *Compression*: minimizes band-width by compressing the production.js file with Google Closure compiler.

Comment: JavaScriptMVC is a huge bloated framework. I doubt you can afford to use it due to mobile limitations.

Comment: @Raynos It's a nice framework to get started quickly (which was a requirement if I understood the question properly). Spine requires additional setup, like including require.js etc...Furthermore you don't need to include the whole JavaScriptMVC stuff but just what you need. But sure, never tried it for mobile devices.

Comment: Their jQuery folder alone is 2MB of source code :\ it's a large bloated framework, you can't afford to load it into a mobile device, you need something light and agile.

Comment: But that's not what's going to be deployed. I have lots of stuff in my webapp, really a lot and I reach a size of ~800KB compressed (CSS included). So in a mobile app I'd probably cut out about 50% so I'd reach about 400kb if at all.

Answer (score 2):

Modular javascript involves two things

- Writing modular code
- Loading modular code

Writing modular code is easy. All you have to do is have loosely coupled code that doesn't rely on global state and exposes itself as a module.

Loading modular code requires using a module loader. require.js as you mentioned is popular. or you can try something more recent like [seajs](http://seajs.com/).

As for other frameworks, you don't really need them, but if you don't know how to do JavaScript architecture then I'd be tempted to say you should use zepto and spine.js.